# Managed package keeps marking object required even with no references

Tags: package, product, beta-managed-package, required

I keep seeing `Product` under Package Requirements even though there are zero references to it anywhere in my package. I have searched through all my files both in my local editor and Developer Console and verified neither `Product` nor `Product2` was present.

This package (in beta -no managed releases yet) used to contain references to `Product2` in one Apex class but they are all removed now. It is worth mentioning that this was the case with a couple other objects too, but once their references were removed they disappeared from Package Requirements.

Any ideas how I could correct this issue?

Comment: Can you unselect the product reference or is it not editable.

Comment: @Eric It is not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by indirect references from child and/or nephew objects. It wasn't obvious at all but the View Dependencies button on the package helped me narrow it down.